# How to position the Angular Material expansion panel arrow icon on the left-hand side

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have upgraded Angular Material to 4.0 in my app. I am using the `<mat-expansion-panel>` as per requirement. The expansion arrow has to be on the left-hand side of the panel, but by default it's displaying on the right-hand side. I have checked for the align option, but I didn't get what I need.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel expanded='true'>
   <mat-expansion-panel-header [ngClass]="tickets-container-header">
      <mat-panel-title>
         <div class="col-md-9">
         {{header}} 
         </div>
      </mat-panel-title>

   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

first you need to import angular material icon and expansion panel module in app.module.ts file,

```
import {MatExpansionModule,MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatIconModule 
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Add this code in your HTML file,

```
    <mat-expansion-panel expanded='true' hideToggle="true" (click)="click()">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header [ngClass]="tickets-container-header">
        <mat-panel-title>
            <mat-icon>{{icon  ? 'keyboard_arrow_down' : 'keyboard_arrow_up' }}</mat-icon>
            <div  class="col-md-9">
            {{header}} 
            </div>
        </mat-panel-title>

      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Add this code in your component file,

```
icon: boolean = false;

click(){
    this.icon = !this.icon;
  }
```

Thanks,

Comment: hideToggle didn't work for hiding the arrow , using css i have done. Thx.

Comment: Instead of using the `icon` field you could use `#panel` on the panel (i.e., `<mat-expansion-panel #panel ...`) and in the `mat-icon` element use `{{panel.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'}}` ... this would remove the need for the `click` event handler.

Answer (score 31):

As of Angular Material 8.1.x, you can use the `@Input() togglePosition`-decorator.

[The documentation states the following](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanel)

> @Input() togglePosition: MatAccordionTogglePosition | The position of the expansion indicator.

Add it to the accordion like this: `<mat-accordion [togglePosition]="'before'">`

Here is a [Stackblitz with an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/togglechevron-expansion-panel)

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me just using css:

```
.mat-expansion-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: I had tried this initially and noticed some weird painting when the accordions animated while having nested expansion panels.  The accepted answer provides much better performance when rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the class "mat-expansion-toggle-indicator-before" on the panel header. Example:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel-header class="mat-expansion-toggle-indicator-before">
    <mat-panel-title>
        A title!
    </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: worked for me.  The expansion arrow is now on the right hand side.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to add function and variable. Just add this style:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header > span.mat-content {
    order: 2;    
}
```

Comment: Don't post code related remarks in comments, you can [edit] your answer and include it there

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `togglePosition` attribute to set the position of toggle arrow to before the title.

```
<mat-expansion-panel expanded='true' togglePosition="before">
   <mat-expansion-panel-header [ngClass]="tickets-container-header">
      <mat-panel-title>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            {{header}} 
         </div>
      </mat-panel-title>
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

It's available in the API section of the documentation.
https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatAccordionTogglePosition

Answer (score 1):

I discovered something interesting.
The .mat-content is spreading across the whole screen.
So if you want to **position the icon** **neither on the right nor on the left** side, but instead just **right next to your "text"** from the mat-content, then just

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep span.mat-content {
    flex: none;
  }
}
```

set flex to none.

The mat-content is then just as wide as the span within uses the space and the mat-indicator icon is right next to it.

Comment: This is the best answer to place adiacent to text

Answer (score 1):

if you need to to the left then you can just use
like this: `<mat-accordion [togglePosition]="'before'">`

but You can simply make this dynamic in away you don't care about the on click event, basically you can just define **#panel**
then you can get expanded value from there, in this way you can locate the icon anywhere such as title or the description

```
    <mat-expansion-panel expanded='true' hideToggle="true" #panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header [ngClass]="tickets-container-header">
        <mat-panel-title>
            <mat-icon>{{panel.expanded ? 'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down' }}</mat-icon>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {{header}}
            </div>
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Angular Decorator "@indicatorRotate"

```
   <mat-icon [@indicatorRotate]="expanded ? 'expanded': 'collapsed'">
     expand_more
  </mat-icon>
```