# Can't bind to 'togglePosition' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-expansion-panel'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I'm using a `mat-expansion-panel` and now I want to move the arrow position. The docs says that I can use the input property `togglePosition` on `mat-expansion-panel`. I've tried it but it gives this error:

```
Can't bind to 'togglePosition' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-expansion-panel'
```

I've imported `MatExpansionModule` in app.module.ts. The `mat-expansion-panel` works perfectly, but if I try to set that property it gives the error.

EDIT:
[This is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dqyklqjynaj) with the example. It's the same as the example in the docs, and I've left only the MatExpansionModule in the imports in module. I don't know why in the stackblitz is working and not in my app.

Comment: could you please create a stackblitz link with source codes ?

Comment: i cant see any mat-expansion-panel in you example , please update as same way as you are getting error please

Comment: @Usr: What version of Angular Material are you using?

Comment: @Usr: It seems `togglePosition` is only available from Angular Material v8.1+. For a workaround, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47033495/6513921